# Unexpected EOF (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a PHP server on which I write both HTML and javascript. I am posting some data from a database into an array, then posting it in my HTML-file and then fetching it from my javascript file. This has worked just fine until I wrote a certain line of code (which is the same kind of command that I have been using all over my document). I tried to make a link this way, but every time I try to run it, it poses the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF
```

I have no idea how to get around this error. I hope you can help me.

The following is the part of my code that works fine before I change it

```
var para5 = document.createElement("button");
document.getElementById("et" + i).appendChild(para5);
var att16 = document.createAttribute("onclick");
att16.value = "window.location.href='/seForslag/?iden=" + i + "'"
para5.setAttributeNode(att16);
var att17 = document.createAttribute("class");
att17.value = "dFsu8t _2CdOjN knapet knapper";
para5.setAttributeNode(att17);
var att18 = document.createAttribute("id");
att18.value = "knap" + i;
para5.setAttributeNode(att18)
var para6 = document.createElement("span");
para6.innerHTML = "Se forslag"
document.getElementById("knap" + i).appendChild(para6)
```

And this is what I want it to be, but does not work

```
var para5 = document.createElement("button");
document.getElementById("et" + i).appendChild(para5);
var att16 = document.createAttribute("onclick");
att16.value = "window.location.href='/seForslag/?iden=" + document.getElementById("divId" + i).innerHTML + "'"
para5.setAttributeNode(att16);
var att17 = document.createAttribute("class");
att17.value = "dFsu8t _2CdOjN knapet knapper";
para5.setAttributeNode(att17);
var att18 = document.createAttribute("id");
att18.value = "knap" + i;
para5.setAttributeNode(att18)
var para6 = document.createElement("span");
para6.innerHTML = "Se forslag"
document.getElementById("knap" + i).appendChild(para6)
```

Here is the PHP that I am fetching data from

```
 <?php
                    $forslagid=array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    ?>
```

and the HTML

```
<div style="display: none;" id="divLength">
              <?php echo sizeof($forslagid) ?>
            </div>

<?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($forslagid); $i++) { ?>
          <div style="display: none;" id="divId<?php echo $i ?>">
            <?php echo $forslagid[$i] ?>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Tell me if you need any more information :)

Comment: As you concatnate the string using double quote, try single quote around the "divId".

Comment: Need to see the entirety of an exemplar of the element with id divId*N*

Comment: @AliSheikhpour If you mean like this, then it does not work: document.getElementById('divId' + i).innerHTML

Comment: @Tibrogargan If you are talking about what is written inside the divs, it is just numbers from the array "forslagid" (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), as you can see in the HTML piece I have provided

Comment: No sir, you have not.  You have provided some PHP that will use some variables that you have not shown to render some HTML that you also have not shown.  The reader has no way of telling if that rendered HTML is causing the issue, which could easily be the case if it's `innerHTML` contains a single quote (`'`)

Comment: is there a reason that `att16.value = "window.location.href='/seForslag/?iden=" + i + "'"` is not followed by a semicolumn `;` ? ( check all lines ) also, make sure that your php file has a closing tag without any hidden characters or lines after that

Comment: @ObmerkKronen No, that was a mistake, but I have now put ; everywhere, and it still does not work

Comment: well.. did you try to escape / encode the url ? but it will be difficult to say exactly without knowing the content of `i` or `el+i`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so i figured it out. Apparently, something in the document made spaces around the numbers in the array, so the link might have been "window.location.href='/seForslag/?iden= 1 '". I have no idea why this happens, but I made it work by adding ".trim()" at the end like this:

```
att16.value = "window.location.href='/seForslag/?iden=" + document.getElementById("divId" + i).innerHTML.trim() + "'"
```